# BigQuery GROUP BY top n categories and group rest in "other"

Tags: google-bigquery

I hit the same task quite often - aggregate data by top X values in categorical variable and roll everything else in "other".

So far I was using this trick:

```
SELECT
year,
if(tt.state is null, "other", t.state) as state_filtered,
count(1) as children
FROM [publicdata:samples.natality] as t
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT state, count(1) as children FROM [publicdata:samples.natality]
  WHERE state is not null
  GROUP BY state
  ORDER BY children DESC
  LIMIT 5
) as tt ON tt.state=t.state
GROUP BY year, state_filtered
ORDER BY year, state_filtered
```

But it is not very clean since I query the same table twice and in real-life examples code gets too complicated. I was looking for a solution using ROLLUP or TOP but didn't figure out anything better.

Does anybody know a better way of doing it?

Comment: If you want to compute top 5 states globally - then there is no way to avoid two scans. But if you want to compute different top 5 states within each year, then there might be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a shortcut solution for you to have top 5 states globally.
No joins - so at least code wise - it does just one scan! And it was twice faster when compared with original code you are using currently.
Not sure if you will like it - depends on what your real scenario is

```
SELECT
  year, 
  state, 
  SUM(children) as children
FROM (
  SELECT
    state,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(year_info, r'^(\w+)') as year,
    INTEGER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(year_info, r'(\w+)$')) as children,
  FROM (
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN pos < 6 THEN state ELSE 'other' END state,
      SPLIT(years_list) as year_info
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        state,
        GROUP_CONCAT(STRING(year) + '|' + STRING(rows)) as years_list,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY children DESC) as pos,
        SUM(rows) as children
      FROM (
        SELECT year, state, COUNT(1) AS rows
        FROM [publicdata:samples.natality]
        WHERE state IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY year, state
      )    
      GROUP BY state
    )
  )
)
GROUP BY year, state
ORDER BY year, state
```

I feel there is a better way to deal with "group_concat/split" trick

Answer (score 3):

You can use Row_Number in a sub-query.

```
SELECT
  IF (RNB<=5, state, "Other") AS state,
  SUM(children) AS Children
FROM (
  SELECT
    state,
    children,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY children DESC) AS RNB
  FROM (
    SELECT
      state,
      COUNT(1) AS children,
    FROM
      [publicdata:samples.natality]
    WHERE
      state IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      state))
GROUP EACH BY
  state
```

Answer (score 3):

I think just one sub-select is enough

```
SELECT 
  year,
  IF (pos <= 5, state, "other") AS state,
  SUM(children) AS children
FROM (
  SELECT
    year,
    state,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY children DESC) AS pos,
    COUNT(1) AS children,
  FROM
    [publicdata:samples.natality]
  WHERE
    state IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY
    year, state
)
GROUP BY year, state
ORDER BY year, state
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution but has a problem. For each year there will be different set of "top 5 states". In my case I was selecting one set for all years. Looks like there is no shortcut for me.